# exception cannot bind URL in JMX server

Tags: java, url, binding, jmx

I want to write a JMX server and client and while writing the client i encountered this problem

I can register my MBean properly but when I am trying to run the server I get the following exception:

> cannot bind URL [rmi://localhost:9999/server]

I configured the server as follows :

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/server");
JMXConnectorServer cs =JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url,null,mbs);
cs.start;
```

Comment: by the way, i used this vm arguments when running -  -Dcom.sun.managment.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.managment.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.managment.jmxremote.ssl=false

Answer (score 0):

1. Check nothing running on the port (netstat)
2. Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost